# Purpose of using parentheses in macros

Tags: c, linux, macros

I am curious to know the use of parentheses for both `filp` and `x` pointers in the following assignment operation:

```
#define init_sync_kiocb(x, filp) \
do { \
struct task_struct *tsk = current; \
(x)->ki_flags = 0; \
(x)->ki_users = 1; \
(x)->ki_key = KIOCB_SYNC_KEY; \
(x)->ki_filp = (filp); \        // This line here
....
....
```

Source:
https://github.com/gp-b2g/gp-peak-kernel/blob/master/include/linux/aio.h#L135

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are used in a macro definition which is handled by the preprocessor as text substitution. The fact that it is text substitution can result in weird expressions. Consider:

```
p = &a_struct_array[10];
init_sync_kiocb(p + 20, filp)
```

without the parens, it turns into:

```
p + 20->ki_filp = (filp);
```

with the parens:

```
(p + 20)->ki_filp = (filp);
```

I couldn't, but I bet similar examples can be found for the filp too, or at least you never know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The left-hand side is just typical safety measure since `x` is a macro parameter. It could expand to something that makes the `->` operator fail unless the "thing that needs to be a struct pointer" is protected.

The right-hand side is less obvious to me but might be done just for reasons of consistency and symmetry; always protect macro arguments with parentheses. Some people treat that as a hard rule, and perhaps that project's style guide does, too.

Answer (score 2):

It is inside a macro. This is common and good habit. Imagine you invoke the macro `init_sync_kiocb` as e.g.

```
init_sync_kiocb(pp?*pp:&x,fil?fil:somfil+1);
```

with the parenthesis this gets expanded as

```
(pp?*pp:&x)->ki_filp = (fil?fil:somfil+1);
```

without parenthesis the macro-expansion would be wrong (typing error, or parsing error):

```
pp?*pp:&x->ki_filp = fil?fil:somfil+1;
```

Comment: It works fine in this case. I just wrote a sample program thinking of the same. But it was working as desired. a = 3 > 5 ? 1 : 0 This operation resulted in a's value to be 0

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to mention this is part of a function macro expansion. Such parameters should always be parenthesised to avoid bugs if the passed-in expressions are complex.